# How to manipulate a data where if a variable gives an output the succeeding variable must give the same output?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr, purrr

How to manipulate a dataset such that if a variable gives a certain output the succeeding variable must give the same output?

We consider `VAR1_2013` and `VAR1_2014` to belong to the same variable, measured in 2013 and 2014 respectively. `VAR2_2013` and `VAR2_2014` are another set of variables, also measured in the year 2013 and 2014, respectively.
I would like to write a code such that if the earlier measurement, i.e.  `VAR1_2013`and `VAR2_2013` are recorded as "YES", the succeeding ones must also be "YES". Otherwise, we leave them as they are.

The thing is I have 6 variables x 6 years, which means 36 variables to manipulate.

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text ="
                 ID VAR1_2013 VAR2_2013 VAR1_2014 VAR2_2014
                 1 YES NO NO NO
                 2 NO NO NO YES
                 3 NA YES NO NO
                 4 NO YES NA NA", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I ran the following code, but obviously, it is not scalable.

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(VAR1_2014 = if_else(!is.na(VAR1_2013) & VAR1_2013 == "YES", "YES", VAR1_2014),
         VAR2_2014 = if_else(!is.na(VAR2_2013) & VAR2_2013 == "YES", "YES", VAR2_2014))
# ID VAR1_2013 VAR2_2013 VAR1_2014 VAR2_2014
# 1  1       YES        NO       YES        NO
# 2  2        NO        NO        NO       YES
# 3  3      <NA>       YES        NO       YES
# 4  4        NO       YES      <NA>       YES
```

Comment: Are the column names always made of "something" followed by a number followed by "_YYYY"?

Comment: Hi, it is usually a variable name followed by "_YYYY". So, "STROKE_2013", "STROKE_2014"... "STROKE_2018"

Comment: See if my answer solves the problem. I have edited it to change several variables that follow a first one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following does what you want and is scalable.

```
nm <- names(df)[-1]
vr <- unique(sapply(strsplit(nm, "_"), '[[', 1))
for(v in vr){
  s <- grep(v, nm, value = TRUE)
  i <- !is.na(df[[ s[1] ]]) & df[[ s[1] ]] == "YES"
  df[[ s[-1] ]][i] <- df[[ s[1] ]][i]
}

df
#  ID VAR1_2013 VAR2_2013 VAR1_2014 VAR2_2014
#1  1       YES        NO       YES        NO
#2  2        NO        NO        NO       YES
#3  3      <NA>       YES        NO       YES
#4  4        NO       YES      <NA>       YES
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I actually want changes to happen to the subsequent years only if there's "yes" on the preceding year. So, if there is "no", we keep it that way. Like in row 2, the last column should be "yes".

Comment: @HNSKD Done, change the code line with `is.na`, everything else remains equal.